# How do I get an edge list from this 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have this 2d list:

```
[['***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***'], ['***', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', '***', 'B5', 'B6', '***', 'B8', 'B9', 'End', '***'], ['***', 'C1', '***', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', '***', 'C8', '***', '***', '***'], ['***', 'D1', 'D2', '***', 'D4', '***', 'D6', '***', 'D8', '***', 'D10', '***'], ['***', '***', 'E2', '***', '***', '***', 'E6', '***', 'E8', 'E9', 'E10', '***'], ['***', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7', 'F8', '***', 'F10', '***'], ['***', 'Start', '***', '***', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', '***', 'G8', 'G9', 'G10', '***'], ['***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***', '***']]
```

I also have a 3d list if that helps:

```
[[['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***']], [['***'], [0], [0], [0], ['***'], [0], [0], ['***'], [0], [0], 'End', ['***']], [['***'], [0], ['***'], [0], [0], [0], [0], ['***'], [0], ['***'], ['***'], ['***']], [['***'], [0], [0], ['***'], [0], ['***'], [0], ['***'], [0], ['***'], [0], ['***']], [['***'], ['***'], [0], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], [0], ['***'], [0], [0], [0], ['***']], [['***'], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], ['***'], [0], ['***']], [['***'], [2], ['***'], ['***'], [0], [0], [0], ['***'], [0], [0], [0], ['***']], [['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***']]]
[[['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***']], [['***'], ['B1'], ['B2'], ['B3'], ['***'], ['B5'], ['B6'], ['***'], ['B8'], ['B9'], 'End', ['***']], [['***'], ['C1'], ['***'], ['C3'], ['C4'], ['C5'], ['C6'], ['***'], ['C8'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***']], [['***'], ['D1'], ['D2'], ['***'], ['D4'], ['***'], ['D6'], ['***'], ['D8'], ['***'], ['D10'], ['***']], [['***'], ['***'], ['E2'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['E6'], ['***'], ['E8'], ['E9'], ['E10'], ['***']], [['***'], ['F1'], ['F2'], ['F3'], ['F4'], ['F5'], ['F6'], ['F7'], ['F8'], ['***'], ['F10'], ['***']], [['***'], ['Start'], ['***'], ['***'], ['G4'], ['G5'], ['G6'], ['***'], ['G8'], ['G9'], ['G10'], ['***']], [['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***'], ['***']]]
```

The '***' represent walls while the strings, e.g. 'B3', represents the path square position

I have tried using:

```
rows      = 8
cols      = 12
offsets   = [(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1)]

def inBoard(r,c): return r in range(rows) and c in range(cols)

def getNeighbours(r,c): return [(r+v,c+h) for v,h in offsets if inBoard(r+v,c+h)] 

links = { (r,c):getNeighbours(r,c) for r in range(rows) for c in range(cols) }

for (r,c),neighbours in links.items():
    wallCount = sum('***' in mazelst[nr][nc] for nr,nc in neighbours) 
    if wallCount:
        print(f"there is are {bombCount} number of walls near {(r,c)}")
```

but I don't know how to get an edge list using this. The edgelist i want is like this:

```
[
  ['B1','B2',1],
  ['B2','B3',1],
  ['B3','C3',1],
  ...
  ['B9','End',1]
]
```